# jQuery accordion not working for me

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion

Im looking for a bit of help using the jQuery accordion.

Basically, i have elements that arent the standard h3 and p tags that it requires out of the box.

The jQuery i have is as follows

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#contentHolder").accordion({
        header: '.clicker'
    });
});
</script>
```

and the HTML that im using is as follows:

```
<div id="contentHolder">

<div id="recipe">
    <img src="style/img/rec-image.jpg"></img>
    <p><span style="color: #5C971C; font-weight: bold;">Stuffs M</span><br />stuff goes here</p>
    <p><a class="clicker" href="#"><img src="style/img/details-btn.jpg"></img></a></p>
    <div class="ingredients" style="margin-top: 136px;">
        <p style="width: 420px;"><span style="color: #5C971C; font-weight: bold;">Ingredients</span><br />2L white vinegar<br />2 cups water</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="recipe">
    <img src="style/img/rec-image.jpg"></img>
    <p><span style="color: #5C971C; font-weight: bold;">Stuffs M</span><br />stuff goes here</p>
    <p><a class="clicker" href="#"><img src="style/img/details-btn.jpg"></img></a></p>
    <div class="ingredients" style="margin-top: 136px;">
        <p style="width: 420px;"><span style="color: #5C971C; font-weight: bold;">Ingredients</span><br />2L white vinegar<br />2 cups water</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

How i want it to work, is when someone clicks on the .clicker href i want the div "ingredients" to slide up and down.

Im hoping someone can help :)

Cheers,

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Probably won't change much but its always better and cleaner to have valid markup. (e.g. `img` tags: are like `<img />` not `<img></img>`. You also have multiple elements with the same id.)

Answer (score 3):

According to [jQuery UI Accordian](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Accordion) docs

```
The content element must be always next to its header.
```

Your "clicker" is inside of a p-element

```
<p><a class="clicker" href="#"><img src="style/img/details-btn.jpg"></img></a></p>
```

Maybe put the "clicker" on the p-element? Or get rid of the p-element. Just make sure the div you are trying to show is the "next" element in the DOM.

Comment: It also seems to be looking for elements in pairs.

Comment: Hmmm ... interesting, i put it in the p tag .. still did nothing

Answer (score 1):

The accordion needs following structure:

```
<div id="contentHolder">
    <div class="clicker">
        <a href="#">first clickable</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        first content
    </div>

    <div class="clicker">
        <a href="#">next clickable</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        next content
    </div>
</div>
```

Also see your example working in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYrBS/).

=== UPDATE ===

Although I had forgotten to say that this is not necessarily 'div' s need to act, but to each block element:

```
<div id="contentHolder">
    <p class="clicker">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="style/img/rec-image.jpg" /><br />
            <span style="color: #5C971C; font-weight: bold;">Stuffs M</span><br />
            stuff goes here<br />
            <img src="style/img/details-btn.jpg" />
        </a>
    </p>
    <p class="ingredients">
        <span style="color: #5C971C; font-weight: bold;">Ingredients</span><br />
        2L white vinegar<br />
        2 cups water
    </p>

    <p class="clicker">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="style/img/rec-image.jpg" /><br />
            <span style="color: #5C971C; font-weight: bold;">Stuffs M</span><br />
            stuff goes here<br />
            <img src="style/img/details-btn.jpg" />
        </a>
    </p>
    <p class="ingredients">
        <span style="color: #5C971C; font-weight: bold;">Ingredients</span><br />
        2L white vinegar<br />
        2 cups water
    </p>
</div>
```

Also see my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYrBS/1/).

Comment: I forgot that you don't want `div`s as element wrappers, I have added an example with `p`s.